# libGDX iOS Support and Performance?

Tags: libgdx

New to libGDX but have read a bit about it. I know I can port to iOS which is outstanding. Has anyone done performance testing, say comparing SpriteKit/Cocos2d to libGDX? I'm also interested to learn if Apple Store (IAP) is fully supported as well as Game Center (and optionally, iCloud) ?

**Update**:
I found this project and it "appears" to support the Apple Store (IAP) and Game Center (Apple's Game Center), but the docs seem a bit sparse, can someone please confirm?

https://github.com/BlueRiverInteractive ... s-bindings

Comment: Probably better question for the libgdx forums than stackoverflow. Oh hey, you beat me to it:  http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=17367&sid=433e04f8dd6ca7c0787de721425fe17d

Comment: LibGDX peeps here too.

Comment: Yeah, but its not really a StackOverflowish question (libgdx questions are fine!).  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Sure it is.  It's asking about iOS support in libGDX, a hot topic and not well covered.  I'm certain someone on Stack has experience with libGDX and can answer the question quite well, helping out numerous others.  Its a technical/coding question, perfectly fine for Stack.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I published 2 games created with libgdx to AppStore and now working on third one. Overall I am very excited how libgdx games work on IOS and I am super excited from libgdx as game engine.

1. **Performance:** I did some test with simple game similar to "Swing Copters" and found that game created with libgdx consumes 15-20% more RAM (on IOS device) that the same game created with Cocos2d, but then I used apportable to run cocos2D game on my Android device and found it almost not playable. Anoher case: one of my games (developed with libgdx) has lots of heavy graphic (like map 5000x5000, levels backgrounds 1920x1080 etc) and it runs without any lags on Iphone5+ devices. So from my experience libgdx performance is more than enough for creating games for IOS.
2. **Other problems:** Sometimes you need to use some external libraries for IOS (like advertise SDK or some kind of analytics). In order to do it with libgdx, you should write robovm bindings "bridge" from Objective C to Java. You are lucky if somebody already did it for you and you can just download binding form [here](https://github.com/BlueRiverInteractive/robovm-ios-bindings) otherwise you will spend plenty of time to write your own binding. Other problem is debugging of your game on IOS. You will not have a normal debugger and the only way to debug your game is log.
3. **IAP, App center etc:** You can check which services are supported and already have robovm bindings by visiting [this link](https://github.com/BlueRiverInteractive/robovm-ios-bindings). In my games I used in app purchases and game center, so they are working for sure.

**Conclusion:** Libgdx is very good choice if you want to develop game game for Android and get working ios version without too much efforts, but if your main focus is IOS and not Android there is no advantages on using libgdx.

**EDIT**

[Unfortunately RoboVM Winding Down](https://robovm.com/robovm-winding-down/).

**EDIT 2**

A new [libGDX backend for Multi-OS engine](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=3925) has been already developed. [Multi-OS engine has been open-sourced by Intel, It’s now being maintained by its originator, Migeran](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=3973).

Comment: hi could you please tell if it works now..most of the libgdx games i found from the app store crashed on opening. also what is the size of the app on an average? I heard it is way bigger than a natively developed one!

Comment: Just tried one of my published games, it works without. If you need link write me to email. About size: I have one game with size 22mb and another with size 33mb. In ios size is 20-30% more. I think size for sure is not show stopper from using libgdx:)

Comment: Does it translate into native code ? Or does it require extra software to be installed on the iOS so that it can run ?

Comment: It translates to native code. Fo user will be no difference between libgdx game and native app, so any extra software doesn't needed to be installed.

Comment: How did you speed up the build process for iOS? it just take for ever to compile a newly created project. Any thoughts about Cocos2d-x vs libGDX?

Comment: It was slow only on first project build when I used libgdx, but now RoboVM is closed and I didn't use the latest libgdx builds, so unfortunately can't help with this. Cocos2d-x - didn't use it, so can't compare(